# jQuery ajax request internet explorer popup blocked

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, popup, explorer

This is my function to retrieve a code by passing a variable to a page :

```
jQuery(function() {

jQuery('#carrelli_selezione').change(function(event){

    var categoria_alimentazione = jQuery('#carrelli_selezione').val();

    jQuery.ajax({

        url: 'test_alimentazione.php',
        //dataType: 'html',
        crossDomain: 'true',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({
            'variabile_alimentazione': categoria_alimentazione
        }),

        success: function(data1) {
            jQuery('#alimentazione_select').html(data1);

        }

    });

});});
```

This passes a variable to the page then I want to load the content in my div...
but explorer doesn't work because block the popup...

How can I work around this ?

the code in php page is a php page with the result of the query and an other script code

`

```
$querystr = "
SELECT DISTINCT wpostmeta.meta_value 
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE wpostmeta.meta_key = 'alimentazione'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN($variabile_alimentazione)
ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC

";

$risultato = $wpdb->get_results($querystr,ARRAY_A);

?>

<select name="alimentazione" id="alimentazione_selezione">
<option selected="selected" value="">Seleziona alimentazione</option>
<?php //global $post; ?><?php foreach ($risultato as $chiave): ?><?php    //setup_postdata($post); ?><option value="<?php echo $chiave['meta_value']; ?>" ><?php echo      $chiave['meta_value']; ?></option><?php endforeach; ?></select>



<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {

var categoria_carrelli = jQuery("#carrelli_selezione").val();

jQuery("#alimentazione_selezione").change(function(event){

    var categoria_elevazione = jQuery("#alimentazione_selezione").val();
    //var categoria_alimentazione = jQuery("#carrelli_selezione").val();

    jQuery.ajax({

        url: "test_elevazione.php",
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({
            "variabile_elevazione": categoria_elevazione,
            "variabile_carrelli": categoria_carrelli
        }),

        success: function(data2) {
            jQuery("#elevazione_select").html(data2);

        }

    });

});

});

</script>`
```

Comment: What popup?...I don't see any code for an `alert` or `prompt` or invoking a new `window` anywhere. Can you show more code?

Comment: I edit the question with the code.

Comment: I didn't found other problem with jquery ajax function... where do I make a mistake?

Comment: I still do not see anything that has to do with a popup, bro. I know english isn't your native language, so maybe you could take a picture of what you're trying to achieve (in a browser other than Internet Explorer) so I can see what "doesn't work". As I said before, and still continue to state, I don't see any popups being created. Also, `data: ({` just needs to be `data: { `; no need for the parenthesis.

Comment: What is the environment for your tests?  Windows 7 with IE8, or something like that?  I am having the same problem.